# Multiple times trigger generation in Zabbix

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I am new to zabbix. I have a basic requirement of monitoring occurrence of different log messages using zabbix. Say, when there is a log message `"server starting"`, zabbix should show that alert. The idea is that if the server (re)starts 10 times in last 10 minutes, the zabbix dashboard (or at any other place) should display that 10 times.

I have done the following for that :

1. Created an item under template MyTemplate:

> ```
> Type : Zabbix Agent (Active)
> key : log[/opt/mylog/logs/abc.log,server starting]
> Type of information : Log
> Update Interval (in sec) : 30
> ```

2. Created a trigger with expression :

> {MyTemplate:log[/opt/mylog/logs/abc.log,server
>   starting].logeventid(1)}=0

With logeventid(1), I am seeing that the alert (trigger) is getting generated only once. It appears only once in the `Dashboard --> Last 20 issues`. If I go to `Monitoring --> Trigger`, I see the alert only once, although the log files have 10 entries of the message `"server starting"` (server restarted 10 times).

Then I set the trigger to following :

> {MyTemplate:log[/opt/mylog/logs/abc.log,server
>   starting].nodata(300)}=0

Now, at `Monitoring --> Trigger`, I see the alert (trigger) 10 times, but, from the `Dashboard --> Last 20 issues` it vanishes just after 300 seconds.

My questions are :

1. What should be the trigger function, I should use? I want to see 10 alerts in zabbix if the same message appears 10 times in the log file within a period of time.
2. With nodata(300), why does the alert vanish after 300 sec?
3. Is it ok if I use 30 minutes instead of 300 seconds as an argument of nodata()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function `logeventid()` is normally used for Windows and VMware event logs. In this case, it should probably not be used and it is suspicious that it fires, which might indicate a bug in Zabbix.

Anyway, you can check "Multiple PROBLEM events generation" box in trigger configuration and the trigger will generate a new PROBLEM event every time the condition is true, regardless of its previous value. Instead of `logeventid()`, you can try using a function that is always true, for instance, `strlen()>0`.

If you wish the trigger to go into OK state after some time, say, 10 minutes, you can add `nodata(10m)`. Then your trigger will look like this:

```
{MyTemplate:log[/opt/mylog/logs/abc.log,server starting].strlen()}>0 and
{MyTemplate:log[/opt/mylog/logs/abc.log,server starting].nodata(10m)}=0
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. Could you please explain more about disadvantage of logeventid()? Also, what happens if I use nodata with 12 hours? The idea is the alerts which was triggered late night should be displayed as problem next morning also (~ 12 hours). Is there any feature/performance impact?

Comment: Regarding logeventid(), your expression might actually be correct from the technical perspective. You check that logeventid(1)=0, i.e., that log event ID does not contain "1". Since there is no event ID associated with regular log files, it is technically good. I misread your expression the first time.

Comment: Regarding nodata() with 12 hours, you can use nodata(12h) without any problems.